# How to make controller to insert time on click and remove time on another click?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4, laravel-8

This is my controller where i want to know what is correct.

```
public function complete($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    if($task->done_at = '' or $task->done_at = null) {
        $task->done_at = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'now' ) );

        $task->save();
    } elseif ($task->done_at !== null) {
        $task->done_at = null;

        $task->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

and this is my index page where there is form for clicking

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.complete', $task->id) }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" name="submit"><p style="border-radius: 50%; color:red"></p></button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: There might be a typo, `$task->done_at = '' or $task->done_at = null` should be `$task->done_at == '' or $task->done_at == null`, with double `=` sign

Answer (score 0):

You can check with that using empty() function. and do not repeat yourself you can also use save function in last after if else condition.

Thanks :)